# Coding string to numeric in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to convert string codes to integer codes

Here is my Excel file

```html
Level1 Level2 Level3 Level4 Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
A B E C 12 14 12 13
D D E C 11 17 16 9
E C C B 14 13 19 8
C E B D 11 12 10 7
B A A D 10 11 7 6
```

A= 4, B=3, C=2, D=1 , E= 0

get this in sheet2

```html
Level1 Level2 Level3 Level4 Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
4 3 0 2 12 14 12 13
1 1 0 2 11 17 16 9
0 2 2 3 14 13 19 8
2 0 3 1 11 12 10 7
3 4 4 1 10 11 7 6
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like you can use VBA to create a `Dictionary` that maps the values to the letters. Makes the translation quick and easy. If you want a non-code solution, then create a table on a separate spreadsheet and use `VLOOKUP` to get the value for each letter.

Comment: @ Peter T- Thanks, Would it be possible for you to show me it. It would be very helpful as I have a large data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ASCII table and some basic maths.

```
dim i as long

for i=65 to 69
    worksheets("sheet1").cells.replace what:=chr(i), replacement:=(69-i)
next i
```

Comment: Maybe you'd best put it inside a procedure.

Comment: @BigBen ... or matchcase:=true.

Comment: Capital `A` is ASCII 65 dec. You can create one with `Chr(65)`. 69 minus 65 is 4. Capital `B` is ASCII 66 dec. You can create one with `Chr(66)`. 69 minus 66 is 3. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as fast as a dictionary, but its clocking at 1 second for 10,000 rows across 4 columns.

Searching in columns A - D down to last row (determined by Col A)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A2:D" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SearchRange.Replace What:="A", Replacement:=4, LookAt:=xlWhole
    SearchRange.Replace What:="B", Replacement:=3, LookAt:=xlWhole
    SearchRange.Replace What:="C", Replacement:=2, LookAt:=xlWhole
    SearchRange.Replace What:="D", Replacement:=1, LookAt:=xlWhole
    SearchRange.Replace What:="E", Replacement:=0, LookAt:=xlWhole
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an area of any worksheet (for example Sheet2) with your chosen mapping of letters to numbers, like this:

```
+--------+-------+
| Letter | Value |
+--------+-------+
| A      |     4 |
| B      |     3 |
| C      |     2 |
| D      |     1 |
| E      |     0 |
+--------+-------+
```

Then, suppose on one of your main worksheets you have a letter in cell `B3="D"`. You can enter a formula into a different cell, perhaps cell `C3`, with your lookup formula: `=VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet2!A2:B10,2,FALSE)`.  (The range A2:B10 in this case would be replaced with the range of your entire letter-to-number table). The formula will return the number value.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this in Sheet2!A2

`=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!A2),Sheet1!A2,69-CODE(Sheet1!A2))`

Fill over/down as needed.